# Binding a view's layout property to an Object controller

Tags: sproutcore, sproutcore-views

I've recently begun working in Sproutcore, which seems to be a really good solution for client side web app development. However, the documentation isn't as thorough or concise as I'd like, so I am struggling with a few things.

Specifically, I'm trying to bind the layout property of one of my views to an object. I've managed this to an extent, in that when the view is rendered it uses the properties from the object, but the problem I'm having is that when the object is updated, the view's dimensions don't change. However, if the change is persistent and I reload the page, it uses the new values.

Is there some sort of limitation in binding layout properties so that they dynamically update, or do I have the wrong approach here?

Comment: can you show the relevant code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this approach will work.   Controllers are not supposed to have anything to do with a view's properties; controllers are ONLY supposed to proxy objects.

One alternative you might want to consider is using the `adjust` method defined on the `SC.View` class.  You can have your view observe a property on the model it represents, and then in the observer call

`this.adjust('height', 30); // or whatever`

I think `adjust` can also be used like

```
this.adjust({
    height: 10,
    width: 20,...
})
```

without knowing more about what you are trying to do, its hard to say more.

**MORE DETAIL**

Ok, so one thing about Sproutcore is you need to be careful to not get in the way of the runloop.  Unfortunately, there isn't much documentation on this.  What I have learned is that you wan't observers to observe things in in their scope only.  So here is an outline of what you want to do.

```
SC.View.extend({
   layout: {...}, // initial properties

   // binding to the text field that adjusting depends on, NOT on 
   // this view's content
   outsidePropertyBinding: "binding.to.textField", 

   outsidePropertyDidChange: function(){
       var outsideProperty = this.get('outsideProperty');
       this.adjust({
          // as shown before
       })
   }.observes('outsideProperty') // <-- this is how you create an observer

});
```

What I've shown here is how to adjust based on something that is changing **outside of this view**.  I created

1)  A binding to the outside property, which SC updates for you
2)  An observer on the bound property, that fires as soon as the value is set, and adjusts the view.  The observer is **observing a property in the view, not out of the view**.

Note that if your view is bound to some content, and its a property on that content itself that changes, then you would do it slightly differently.  You wouldn't need the binding to the outside property, you could instead just observe `'*content.relevantproperty'`.  The `*` before `content` tells the observer that the content object itself might change (if the views content object can change).

Comment: That sounds promising. At the moment, all I'm doing is trying to familiarise myself with the framework and try out a few techniques I'll need for a project I want to get started on. Specifically, all I'm trying to do here is make a View that changes size when the user adjusts a textbox or similar.

I don't suppose you'd be able to supply some example code for the method you suggested? It looks like what I'm after, but I'm not sure how to make an observer in the View, as it's not something I've come across in any documentation.

Comment: @jiminizer, what do you mean 'adjusts a textbox'.  Do you mean that the user will enter a value in the textbox and you will then set the layout on a *different* view?

Comment: The textbox will be in view1, changing the value will change the size of view2. At any rate, your response is extremely helpful, it's exactly what I've been looking for. I'll give it a go later, but for now, I'll accept this answer. Thanks!

Comment: I've tried implementing what you put above, but the DidChange property isn't firing. Any ideas what might be causing that? There doesn't seem to be anything different between my view and yours aside from variable names (I only changed "outsideProperty" to a more appropriate name). If I access outsideProperty through a JS console, it's updating, it's just not causing the observer method to fire.

Comment: Turns out I wasn't using the set method when setting the property - it works great now! Thanks for your help.